# Deploy VUE application on IIS

Tags: vue.js, iis, web-applications, vue-router, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a VUE frontend application on IIS.
The routing is working fine in dev mode, however, something seems to break in the routing when I host my VUE app on IIS.
When I click on a link, I want to navigate to another page within the same single-page-app without having the website to refresh.
Instead what happens is that the route in the URL updates and the page refreshes, which results in a 404 Page Not Found error.

Can someone advise how to configure IIS to handle the routing of a VUE frontend app (I'm using vue-router)?